# Artifactory hide repositories?

Tags: artifactory

I'm setting up our new Artifactory Repositories. We are moving from Nexus.
In Nexus I could choose not to "publish" a URL to a given repository.

That is: I would like my users to always access all repositories through a subset of our virtual repositories. Is this possible?

That is Virtual repository A points to local repo B and remote repo C.
I would like that B and C is NOT accessible to my users directly.. but only through A.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

virtual repositories are supported in artifactory as well. Virtual acts a single repo to the remote users. Any packages part of local/remote can be accessed via a single virtual repo

Comment: I know. My question was how do I hide the local and remote repositories from direct access?

Comment: I guess you can manage that using permission Link--> https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions

Comment: Permissions are managed through permission Targets. These can only be defined for "physical" repositories. And I actually want the users to access these repositories.. just not directly... but only through a virtual repo.